# How large is the download file?

Tags: 14.04

I want to download Linux to my 16mb cf card. Please tell me if it will fit.The file seemed to say that it was 1.5 GBbut the website claims it is 64-bit.

Comment: seems misleading to say 64-bit!

Comment: "64-bit" refers to the version of Ubuntu that is designed to run on 64-bit processors (such as recent Intel and AMD CPUs, as opposed to older, 32-bit processors). It doesn't refer to the size of the download file.

Comment: can i commpress the file to fit on a 1gb cf

Comment: No, it's already compressed and won't work if you try to compress it further. Unfortunately you'll need a larger CF card or USB stick to install regular Ubuntu. However, there's a lightweight version of Lubuntu that can fit on a 1GB CF card. It's called Lubuntu and you can download it at http://lubuntu.me

Comment: @j.doe There is nothing misleading. 64-bit refers to the x86_64 processor architecture - not 64 file size bits. Do you think an OS will fit in 64 bits?

Comment: sure.i think a os will fit in 64 bits

Answer (score 5):

The download file is indeed 1.5 gigabytes. "64-bit" refers to the type of computer processor it runs on, and is unrelated to the size of the download. Unless your CF card is decades old, I'm guessing it's 16 gigabytes, not 16 megabytes, and should have enough capacity to hold the Ubuntu installation.

Please let me know if this helps, or if you have further questions or clarifications needed.

Comment: I still have a 16MB CF card lying around :)